# Добавить html тег в конце каждого li в списке

Tags: javascript

Как добавить `<span></span>` внутри каждого `<li>` после основного контента при помощи чистого javascript? Пробовала и `getElementsByTagName`, и `querySelectorAll`, и `getElementsByClassName`, и `getElementById`, но ничего не получилось.

```
<div class="g_b1_paragraph_text">
<ul>
<li>Компактный, лёгкий, ударопрочный</li>
<li>Запас энергии: <strong>5000 измерений</strong></li>
<li>Время измерения: <strong>9 сек</strong></li>
<li>Большой дисплей, крупный шрифт</li>
<li>Одна большая <strong>удобная кнопка</strong></li>
<li>Термометр для измерения температуры помещения</li>
<li><strong>Память на 365 измерений</strong></li>
<li>Таймер для напоминаний, подключение к ПК</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. querySelector(), querySelectorAll() 2. insertAdjacentHTML(), и цикл какой нить как пример forEach() это все что надо для этого

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На чистом js тоже можно одной строчкой обойтись. Другой вопрос, зачем там `span` нужен? Может проще сделать псевдоэлементом на `css`?

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(el => {el.innerHTML += '<span></span>'});
```

```css
li span{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: .5em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Компактный, лёгкий, ударопрочный</li>
  <li>Запас энергии: <strong>5000 измерений</strong></li>
  <li>Время измерения: <strong>9 сек</strong></li>
  <li>Большой дисплей, крупный шрифт</li>
  <li>Одна большая <strong>удобная кнопка</strong></li>
  <li>Термометр для измерения температуры помещения</li>
  <li><strong>Память на 365 измерений</strong></li>
  <li>Таймер для напоминаний, подключение к ПК</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я вас правильно понял вам нужно именно это:

```
let liElems = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');///Или ваш селектор внутри скобок
liElems.forEach((el)=>{
  let newSpan = document.createElement('span');
  newSpan.innerHTML = 'Ваш текст';
  el.append(newSpan);
});
```

Как работает:

Получаем все элементы li в вашем HTML

```
let liElems = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
```

С помощью NodeList.forEach() перебираем все эти элементы с определённой функцией которой мы передаём эти элементы по очереди.

```
(el)=>
{

}
```

Это безымянная функция вместо этого мы можем написать

```
function(el){

}
```

Внутрь функции мы кладём следующий код который будет выполнен для каждого li

Далее создаём элемент внутри скрипта

```
let newSpan = document.createElement('span');
```

Вписываем в этот элемент (который мы создали внутри нашего скрипта)текст

```
newSpan.innerHTML = 'Ваш текст';
```

И далее когда наш новый элемент готов к выводу на страницу подгружаем его

```
el.append(newSpan); ///если хотите вставить этот элемент в начало li то вам нужно будет использовать функцию Element.prepend() вместо Element.append()
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, как там с чистым js-ом, а на jQuery - одной строчкой:

```
$('li').append('<span></span>');
```